# Implementing numpy.tensordot code in C++ for arrays having different dimensions

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to implement numpy.tensordot like summation of product for two different matrices in C++. Although I understand the implementation for arrays of same dimension, I'm unable to figure out the method to use for multiplying a 2-D array of size `3 * 3` with an array of size `3 * 600 * 600`. The resultant array should have size `3 * 600 * 600`.

To understand the intuition, I tried to work through  `3 * 3 * 3` and  `3 * 3` arrays on pen and paper but it lead to inconsistent results.

A sample numpy version of my code is as below:

```
import numpy as np
R = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
XYZ = np.arange(3*600*600).reshape*3, 600, 600)

result = np.tensordot(R, XYZ, axes = 1)
```

For ease I'm attaching a link to [numpy.tensordot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html#numpy.tensordot) documentation.

Comment: I don't think you should use `np.tensordot` as a model for anything.  At it's core it just reshapes and transposes the input arrays so that it can use an ordinary 2d `dot` (matrix multiplication.  It may then transpose and reshape back.  The `axis` parameter is often confusing.  `matmul` is proving to be more useful.  Or for full control over axes, `np.einsum`.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the quick reply... I tried with ```np.einsum``` as well but for some reason the operands don't reconcile to give the same answer as ```np.tensordot```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [129]: R = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
     ...: XYZ = np.arange(3*600*600).reshape(3, 600, 600)
```

`tensordot` has 2 styles of `axes`, the scalar and the tuple:

```
In [130]: result = np.tensordot(R, XYZ, axes=1)
In [131]: result.shape
Out[131]: (3, 600, 600)
```

The `einsum` equivalent is:

```
In [132]: res1 = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl',R, XYZ)
In [133]: res1.shape
Out[133]: (3, 600, 600)
In [134]: np.allclose(result, res1)
Out[134]: True
```

and the tuple axes equivalent:

```
In [135]: res2 = np.tensordot(R, XYZ, axes=(1,0))
In [136]: res2.shape
Out[136]: (3, 600, 600)
In [137]: np.allclose(result, res2)
Out[137]: True
```

I think the tuple axes style was original, and the integer axes added on top of that.  Sometime ago I worked out how the interger cases were translated into the tuple inputs, but I've forgotten the details.

Anyways, the sum-of-products dimension is the last of `R` and the first of `XYZ`.

Another way is to multiply element-wise with broadcasting, and then summing:

```
In [139]: res4=(R[:,:,None,None]*XYZ[None,:,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
In [140]: np.allclose(result, res4)
Out[140]: True
```

By compressing the last dimensions of `XYZ` to one, we get the conventional `dot` product, where the sum-of-products is the last of the first, and 2nd to the last of second:

```
In [141]: res5 = (R@XYZ.reshape(3,-1)).reshape(3,600,600)
In [142]: np.allclose(result, res5)
Out[142]: True
In [143]: res6 = (R.dot(XYZ.reshape(3,-1))).reshape(3,600,600)
In [144]: np.allclose(result, res6)
Out[144]: True
```

I believe `tensordot` is effectively doing [143].

Comment: thanks..... this clears up on how to plan the for loops. Reading your answer combined with ```np.einsum``` documentation helped a lot. I hope they deprecate ```np.tensordot``` it is wildly confusing.